# SQL Server getting values for CHECK

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to get the values for a `CHECK` Constraint

Example

```
CONSTRAINT TheCollumn CHECK (TheCollumn IN('One','Two','Three') )
```

I want to get the `'One' 'Two' 'Three'` from a Query which I can then use to populate a Dropdown without having to retype the values in the dropdown list

Comment: It is stored in a pre-parsed form within the server, but every mechanism I'm aware of for extracting information on the constraint re-constructs SQL. So, do you want to pull a full SQL parser into your system?

Comment: Yes I want to pull the full SQL from the Server, because I might be able to analyze that and pull the data out from that result

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want a foreign key constraint and a reference table:

```
create table refTheColumn (
    name varchar(255) primary key
);

. . .
    constraint fk_thecolumn foreign key (theColumn) references refTheColumn(name);
```

Then you can populate the list with the reference table.

Comment: I can do it this way, but what I want to achieve is a 'hacky' way to use my Code Generater to use these values and create a Enum Type  because SQL Server doesn't have enums

Comment: @DonaldJansen: enums are a poor replacement for a proper foreign key constraint. Gordon's suggestion *really* is the best approach

Comment: Currently I do it like this
Generated code will have the Property and the Partial code will have an Property_Enum which converts the value back and forth

Answer (score 2):

It's a bad idea, but here's the general approach:

```
USE tempdb
CREATE TABLE #tmp (v varchar(50));
ALTER TABLE #tmp ADD CONSTRAINT TheCollumn  CHECK(v IN ('One', 'Two', 'Three'));
GO


SELECT definition FROM sys.check_constraints WHERE Name = 'TheCollumn'
```

Would output:

```
([v]='Three' OR [v]='Two' OR [v]='One')
```

You'd have to parse that in code (but parsing it in SQL would be very challenging and unwise).  A foreign key, as Gordon Lindoff suggests, is definitely cleaner/easier to work with.

More reasons why this is a bad idea:

- If the check constraint were defined differently, it may store it differently (hence Damien_The_Unbeliever's point about needing a SQL parser).  For example, it might be AND clauses, or it might point to a function (consider `[v] = right(SomeOtherColumn, 5)`, and now you have to interpret that)
- The `sys` tables (`sys.check_constraints`) could change in future versions and isn't considered a reliable way to access this data.  Your code might not survive a SQL upgrade (whereas using a reference table would).  Even worse, it might not throw an exception on an upgrade that changes the SQL server functionality being leveraged, but it might create a bug that's difficult to track down or reproduce across environments (i.e. prod upgrades but dev doesn't).

Comment: Not a good idea, but a good answer:  definitely a clever approach.

Comment: I Understand that Gordon Linoff is probably the best answer using a table but then I would need to get a way of specifying that the table is used as an Enum in C# and not as an actual object, but what you have given here is Exactly what I wanted for my experiment.  I am going to accept Gordon's answer (for future readers) but I am definitely going to play with this code

Comment: If you're trying to populate a combobox, I'd think a `List<string>` would be more useful than an `Enum`...  If you need a key for each list item, your reference table could have an additional column for it, and populate a `Dictionary<int, string>` from it.